# Android error with ListView in adapter : java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm facing this error in displaying a List View. The problem is in the adapter but I couldn't find the solution. This in my logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at com.client.alm.WorkItemAdapter.getView(WorkItemAdapter.java:47)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
```

And this is my adapter :

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.client.alm.model.WorkItem;
import com.client.alm.model.WorkItemContainer;

public class WorkItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WorkItem> {

    private WorkItemContainer container;
    private Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;

    public WorkItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            WorkItemContainer container) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId,container.getWorkitems());
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.container = container;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageType;
        TextView type;
        TextView priority;
        ImageView imagePriority;
        TextView key;
        ImageView imageStatus;
        TextView status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageType = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageTypeWorkitem);
            holder.type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.typeWorkitem);
            holder.imagePriority = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imagePriority);
            holder.key = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.key);
            holder.imageStatus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageStatus);
            holder.status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.status);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        WorkItem workitem = container.getWorkitems().get(position);
        holder.type.setText(workitem.getType());
        // holder.imageType.setImageResource(workitem.getIcon());
        holder.priority.setText(workitem.getPriority());
        holder.key.setText(workitem.getKey());
        holder.status.setText(workitem.getStatus());

        return row;
    }

}
```

And this is my activity :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.client.alm.model.WorkItem;
import com.client.alm.model.WorkItemContainer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class WorkItemActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wokitemlist);

        new LoadWorkitem().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all Workitems by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadWorkitem extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WorkItemActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Workitems ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting JSON
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            RestClient rc = new RestClient(
                    "http://10.0.2.2:8080/SpringRestWebServices/rest/workitem/getworkitem");

            try {
                rc.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rc.getResponse();
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultat) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            WorkItemContainer container = gson.fromJson(resultat,
                    WorkItemContainer.class);

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            WorkItemAdapter adaptateur = new WorkItemAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.workitemitem, container);

            ListView listViewWorkitem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            listViewWorkitem.setAdapter(adaptateur);
            super.onPostExecute(resultat);
        }
    }

}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your adapter change

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
```

with

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

I would also move this line from the `getView` to the class constructor, so you call it just one time.

But anyway, as also @geeth pointed, its a good practice to instantiate your adapter with the `Activity` context instead the `Application` one otherwise you could have some strange behaviour (for instance, if you activity is themed, using application context the wrong theme would be applied to your `ListView` rows)

Comment: Thank you, I did what you said but I get this new error, I updated my question. Thank you for helping

Comment: I'm glad that helped but you can't change the question. If you have other problems, ask another question.

Comment: Ok I'm going to ask an other question Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You probably send the Application's `context` instead of the Activity's `context`.
please say on which line you get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Replace below code

```
 /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        WorkItemAdapter adaptateur = new WorkItemAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.workitemitem, container);
```

With

```
 /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        WorkItemAdapter adaptateur = new WorkItemAdapter(
               WorkItemActivity.this, R.layout.workitemitem, container);
```

You will solve your issue.